# Laravel - Can I make l make login like Login with Facebook via Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0

I have two laravel applications. 1 as a client([www.myclient.com](http://www.myclient.com)) and another laravel app([www.myserver.com](http://www.myserver.com)) and I would like to build the following case.

1. When user wants to login on [www.myclient.com](http://www.myclient.com) he gets redirected to [www.myserver.com](http://www.myserver.com) and there on a page he writes the username and password he have with [www.myserver.com](http://www.myserver.com) and once he is successfully logged in he gets redirected back to [www.myclient.com](http://www.myclient.com) where is now also logged.

I've been reading this guide: https://blog.logrocket.com/laravel-passport-a-tutorial-and-example-build/

However there are only API requests in the end of the guide, there is no redirect of the user to the server app to provide the username and password directly on the server's page. I don't want to send username and password over the API.

Am I even looking correctly by trying to achieve such functionality with OAuth2?

Basically I would like to achieve functionality LIKE "Login with Facebook" where you get redirected and you fill your login data there.

Can you suggest any other approach or guide?

Comment: Agreed, API authentication usually works a bit differently than UI app authentication, because with the API you don't usually deal with sessions. But yes you could use OAuth2 to make a single sign on solution which will federate identity between your two applications.

Comment: @ADyson can you suggest any guide to follow while making the UI app authentication ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything specific personally, and besides, recommendations for such things are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here